# ncurses: wgetch fails to read correctly after moving / resizing window

Tags: c++, c, cursor, ncurses, curses

I am having a hard time trying to get `wgetch` to read data from a window after moving and resizing it.

Upon input, I move the window up and increase it's height by 1 too. I then clear the window and write data back to it. The problem is when I do `wgetch` (or `mvwgetch`) it positions the input cursor at the previous position before I moved the window up.

Here's my code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    WINDOW *win=initscr();
    int y,x,i=1;
    getmaxyx(win, y, x);

    //creates a sub windows 1 col high
    WINDOW *child=derwin(win, i, x, y-i, 0); 

    //doc says to touch before refresh
    touchwin(win);

    //print to child
    waddstr(child, "hello");
    wrefresh(child);
    wrefresh(win);

    noecho();
    while(wgetch(child)!='q') {
            ++i;
            mvderwin(child, y-i, 0);
            wresize(child, i, x);
            touchwin(win);

            wclear(child);

            waddstr(child,"hello");
            wrefresh(child);
            wrefresh(win);
    }
    delwin(child);
    delwin(win);
    endwin();
}
```

Here the word "hello" does move up as expected, however, the input cursor is in the wrong place. Using `mvwgetch` still causes the same problem. `cbreak()`, `noecho()` and `scrollok(child)` also don't seem to be helping.

Thanks

EDIT: updated version better displaying the problem http://liveworkspace.org/code/31DruQ$0

Comment: Is this being compiled as C or C++? What compile options do you use? You said `input cursor is in the wrong place` what is the "wrong" place? Where is it and where would you expect it to be?

Comment: @Mike, the code compiles and presents the same problem with a C or C++ compiler, the project it is going into is C++. What I mean by the wrong place, is say if I move a derived window from 0,0 to 10,10 and wgetch then window get redraw in it's old place 0,0.

Comment: PS: I do not consider a creating a window in the right place an equivalent to moving the frame unless it can be shown that I have misunderstood what wresize and mvderwin are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have to catch SIGWINCH, that signal is sent when you resize the terminal. Do an endwin(),  a refresh(), and then repaint your windows. Cursor position is relative to the windows, not the actual terminal size. The windows are not resized automatically.

Edit: Right, you're actually resizing the windows, not the terminal. In that case, first of all, do a wrefresh on the child LAST, the cursor shown on the screen is the one of the refresh that happened last.

Put a box around your subwindows and check that they're actually getting resized / moved properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The terminal is not been resized though. I just want to resize and reposition the subwin inside of the parent (not because the terminal size has change but the data I want present). I don't need to called endwin for that?

Comment: When you move a window, the cursor position is probably undefined. If you want to make sure it's in a certain place, keep a variable with the cursor positions relative to the window size, and change it appropriately when you do operations on the window. Use wmove(3) to set the cursor's position explicitly within the window.

Comment: Again thanks, I have swapped the refreshed around, the issue now is that it is writing hello now to both the top line of the child and to old position of window. The cursor still prompts for input at the old position too.

Comment: even if I explicitly state the cursor position with mvwgetch, mvwaddstr or just wmove, it still prompts in the wrong place, I'll uploads my current version with the changes you have suggested. I really appreciated your help.

Comment: here is the link to the code with your recommended changes, same issue (except now it is trying to draw the window in both it's new and old position. Any help would be great!   http://liveworkspace.org/code/31DruQ$0

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/FYaKusKw -- Seems like wresize doesn't work the way you think it does, or dermove doesn't work the way you think it does. It doesn't seem to want to move window up. Perhaps you shouldn't be drawing directly to stdscr, either. Read the docs more thoroughly.

Comment: I thought I had read the docs inside and out :/ the thing is if I do not do a `wgetch(...)` then it works *perfectly*. Thanks for your solution re building the derived window seems to fix it (it seems I can safely remove the endwin and extra refreshes), but it's a bit of a hack